# How to make a container move to a position in a certain amount of time, no matter the distance

Tags: javascript, html, css

So say you have a `button` element that when clicked moves an `absolute`ly positioned `div` from the bottom of the page, to the top of the page and you add a `transition` style with a duration of 1 second so it animates smoothly. The problem is, the longer the page, the faster the `div`'s speed to match the duration of the `transition`.

My question is this: How can I make it so that the `div` maintains a certain speed, no matter how small or large the page is; for example, the `div` moves 5px a second (it doesn't get any faster or slower) and it doesn't stop until it reaches its destination.

I tried using the `transition` style but as I mentioned before, The `div`'s speed increases and I don't want it to, I want it to maintain a certain speed.

Comment: your `transition` time should be equal to Distance divided by Desired Speed.

Comment: Yes, you need JS for this.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, it was really stupid. It had to do with my `position` style. I did `position:absolute` instead of `position:fixed` which somehow works now even though I didn't change anything.

I was thinking of doing `` div.style.transitionDuration = `${(document.getElementsByTagName('HTML')[0].outerHTML.length - document.body.scrollTop) / 100}ms`; ``. I'm not even sure if that works because I haven't tested it out properly.

I don't think this is the actual answer to my question because I *did say that it was positioned absolutely* so it's kinda my fault. I thought maybe I should share this :)